# Generate pdf using domPDF does not generating correctly

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a function that will generate a pdf file then email it to someone. I tried to debug it using `return view` first then when i saw it in the network tab, it is correct. But when I email it then I will view the pdf there, the pdf styles is not applied or rendered properly. Can someone tell me what should I do about this and what is the problem?

Here is my controller

```
        $css = 'health/css/bootstrap.min.css';
        $data_type = pathinfo($css, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $css_data = file_get_contents($css);

        $path = 'health/img/logo.png';
        $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data = file_get_contents($path);
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);


       //return view('emails.form',compact('base64','css_data')); test


        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('emails.form',compact('base64','css_data'));

        $beautymail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
        $beautymail->send('emails.welcome', [], function($message)use($pdf)
        {
            $message
                ->from('testemail@gmail.com','TEST')
                ->to('ronald.b@gmail.com', 'Test')
                ->attachData($pdf->output(), "asdf.pdf")
                ->subject('Welcome!');
        });
```

When I tried to do first

```
return view('emails.form',compact('base64','css_data'));
```

What i get is the correct one, like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O0Yw.jpg

Then when i comment the return function and proceed to the email, what i get is like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CViG.jpg

I dont know what is happening. Please help if you got some idea. Thanks..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out that the package has many bugs in it. I tried to use `wkhtmltopdf` which is for php and I saw a wrapper for laravel and i found it at github which is `laravel-snappy`. I got good results and my answer was solved.

It has the same code structure with `dompdf` but you have to download `wkhtmltopdf` tool and save it to your computer in order to work.